# A specific definition of the verb 'see'

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, definition

In the following three sentences, the verb 'see' have been used with the same definition.

> A game that sees people playing dead.
>
> A stunt that sees people eating corn off a rotating drill.
>
> Latest internet fad sees daredevils throw themselves to the ground.

I've consulted multiple dictionaries to search for a 'see'
 definition that closely matches its usage above. However, none of the entries I scanned through is satisfactory to me. Please explain what 'see' means in those examples, and if possible provide a link to the right entry or even idiom.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the same as "viewing with one's eyes."

It means that an event shows a person x.

You could replace it with **in which**.

> A stunt in which people people eat corn off a rotating drill.
>
> A game in which people play dead.

It expresses what the action is.